# Manipulate control on other form

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to manipulate a PictureBox(`pBATalk`) to show whenever I close a form(`PAInput`). So basically I want to show a picture, whenever the 2nd form is closed.

**2nd Form**

```
        public void PAInput_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            fPAMain.PATalkActive(false);
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

**MainForm:**

```
    public void PATalkActive(bool active)
    {
            //MessageBox.Show("");
        if (active == true)
        {
            pBPATalk.Hide();
        }
        if (active == false)
        {
            pBPATalk.Show();
        }
    }
```

Whenever I close `PAInput` it will trigger `PATalkActive`, but will only fire the `MessageBox.Show("");` and not the `pBATalk.Hide();` or `pBATalk.Show();`

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious.  Have you tracked through the code by placing break points at pBPATalk.Show() to see if that code is reached?  If so, have you manually made the control visible?  Have you tried a this.Refresh() after the Show() statement to force your form to repaint?

Comment: @Spevy I've also thought of this, but that wasn't the case unfortunately. It's strange that it does "use" code which is read/read-only though. I suspect it might be a permission's thing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not so sure about what you are trying to accomplish here but first of all you're keeping PAInput open, with this line    e.Cancel = true    . Besides that,     MessageBox.Show("");     will open a modal window displaying a text, until it is closed the rest of the method won't run.

Comment: The purpose of the `MessageBox` is to test if the code was reached from the moment it was called upon, the placement of the code itself is not that important, since it's just to verify if it's used.

Also, I've just disabled the `e.Cancel` and the code still won't hide or show the `pBPATalk`. @zalomon

Comment: @BRO_THOM Don't use MessageBox for debugging since it can interfere with other processes.  Use a debug break or Debug.WriteLine, etc.

Comment: @LarsTech, I just used a `Debugger.Break();` in the `if(active==false)` code and it did break, so I can assume it would have reached the code. In the meanwhile I've also used `((PictureBox)(this.UserControlPanel.Controls[0])).Show();` to append to the picturebox(I just tested this and it reached the control's name, so it's configured properly). That didn't work either.

Comment: I was thinking about this, is this pBPATalk variable an instance of the form in wich the picture should be displayed? how do you assign it? Besides that, how do you pass the picture to be displayed to your form?